# Express App suddenly broken for unknown reason on port 3000

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuex

I'm really confused my express app was working just fine until I made some modifications and everything is now broken. I checked out to a previous commit when everything was working but it's still broken.

I get this error in the browser :

```
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/styles.bundle.css/ 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/bootstrap-social.css/ 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/font-awesome.css/ 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/custom.css/ 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js/ 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/mainClient.js/ 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/register.js/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Files are not found, here's my server log :

```
[0] GET / 304 47.615 ms - -
[0] GET /styles.bundle.css/ 404 0.928 ms - 157
[0] GET /bootstrap-social.css/ 404 0.578 ms - 160
[0] GET /font-awesome.css/ 404 1.283 ms - 156
[0] GET /custom.css/ 404 0.910 ms - 150
[0] GET /app.bundle.js/ 404 1.455 ms - 153
[0] GET /mainClient.js/ 404 1.651 ms - 153
[0] GET /register.js/ 404 2.128 ms - 151
```

I don't know why it started adding those "/" at the end of paths...
Does anyone has an idea of what's going on ?

Note: I was trying to implement connect-history-api-fallback to use my VueRouter on a single page. But I really don't understand why the problem would persist after a git rollback !

Comment: App works when I change my port to 4000 !?

Comment: Don't serve static files from express. Use a non-application web server like nginx, and in production, a content delivery network (CDN). A CDN charges you per terabyte, cloud instances charge you per uptime. It's very cost inefficient to serve files from application servers. Reserve your application servers for APIs and dynamic content. If you absolutely have to, put a reverse proxy cache in front of it.

Comment: I've googled a bit but I can only find resources that explain how to run nginx on production, do you know of any tutorial for running in development on my local machine ?